# Long error in contour plot python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, contour

I am trying to create a contour plot with the x coordinates being label EF and y being labeled EB and z being a function labeled a. It returns a long error posted below. Any help would be appreciated.
The error is

```
File "contour.py", line 19, in <module>
c = plt.contour(EF,EB,a)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2016, in contour
    ret = ax.contour(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7326, in contour
    return mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1088, in __init__
    ContourSet.__init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.py", line 686, in __init__
    self._process_args(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1101, in _process_args
    x, y, z = self._contour_args(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1148, in _contour_args
    x,y,z = self._check_xyz(args[:3], kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1180, in _check_xyz
    raise TypeError("Input z must be a 2D array.")
TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array.
```

Comment: Didn't I answer something about this code half an hour ago?

Comment: @Jblasco: if it's a duplicate question, why not just mark it as so, or at least give a link.

Comment: tom10, I didn't mark it as a duplicate because I don't think it is. I remember the code, not the question, and the link seems to be gone. I guess it was just erased for some reason.

Comment: The error from the previous post was something like why `matplotlib.contour` raises an error. It's because it should be `matplotlib.pyplot.contour`. I think once OP realized how simple the mistake was, he self-deleted the post.

Comment: Doesn't matter, really, shouldn't have raised the question ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error states that

```
TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array.
```

if you look at the sizes of the input objects:

```
print EF.shape, EB.shape, a.shape
(51,) (51,) (51,)
```

you'll see that these are **not** 2D arrays. Did you intend to use `X` and `Y` instead?

When I make the change to

```
a = ((1+.5*(np.exp(1.7*X)+np.exp(1.7*Y)+np.exp(1.7*(X+Y))))/(1+np.exp(1.7*X)+np.exp(1.7*Y)+np.exp(1.7*(X+Y))))
c = plt.contour(EF,EB,a,30)
```

The output is

[image]

It looks like you may need to adjust your parameter space since all the interesting stuff is around `(0,0)`.

Comment: Yup exactly what I was looking fro. Thank You!!

Comment: No problem and welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to upvote good answers and mark those accepted if they solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to creat `a` as a meshgrid, using `X` abd `Y` instead of `EF` and `EB`:

```
a = ((1+.5*(np.exp(1.7*Y)+np.exp(1.7*X)+np.exp(1.7*(Y+X))))/(1+np.exp(1.7*Y)+np.exp(1.7*X)+np.exp(1.7*(Y+X))))
```

Another thing, if you create your meshgrids using `copy=False` it may prevent you from running out of memory:

```
(X,Y) = np.meshgrid(EF,EB, copy=False)
```

In this case it creates a view of your original 1D arrays.

Comment: Nice point about `copy=False`, I didn't even know that was possible! Combined with `meshgrid`'s new ability to create multidimensional arrays (d>2), I can replace a ton of my helper functions.